# django-cms: attributes and methods available to current page

Tags: django, django-cms, current-page

I have been learning `Django-CMS` for a while now. I was trying to hook one of my app to a cms page while still using template assigned to it. I came to know that one can retrieve current template from `request.current_page` object. I searched a lot on `current_page` but could not get any decent document on it.

I was wondering what other attributes and methods are defined in `current_page`..

What is the best way to get every information(title, menu, template, plugins, apps attached, etc) on the current page ?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/middleware/page.py) could help a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digging into the source it seems that `current_page` has all the attributes and methods from `cms.models.pagemodels.Page` model.